# Ошибка линковки библиотеки libm.so

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь скомпилировать проект на C. Компиляция проходит успешно, а вот на этапе линковки возникают проблемы с libm.so. Компоновщик упорно ее не видит. Использую компилятор gcc под ОС CentOS. Много раз пересмотрел Makefile, в нем вроде все корректно. Я не очень знаком с компиляцией gcc, но насколько я понял -lm должно решить проблему (компоновщик автоматически разрешает путь к библиотеке), однако это не помогает. Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как можно решить проблему?

**PS** Строка компиляции и линковки примерно такая:

```
gcc source1.c source2.c -L. mylib.a -lm -static
```

**PPS** Может дело в `-static`?

Comment: Может, пути для поиска библиотек неправильно прописаны?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, при указанном ключе `-v` gcc выдаст информацию о том, где он ищет библиотеки для линковки.

Comment: По идее, сам компилятор должен знать где у него libm.so находится, но я пробовал добавлять путь и в Makefile, и в переменную окружения PATH, но ничего не помогает...

Comment: За ключ '-v' - спасибо: не знал про такое)

Comment: Если я правильно помню, нужен не `PATH`, а `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Или ключ `-L` (именно большое `L`).

Comment: Может LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Тоже пробовал)

Comment: Не, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` — для динамических библиотек.

Comment: Ээээ! `-L.` Вот и причина.

Comment: Вы ж ему сказали, что путь для библиотек — это `.`. Вот он и не может найти.

Comment: А не может быть что флаг -static пытается статически слинковать и libm, заодно с моими библиотеками? (см. обновление вопроса)

Comment: Хм. Следующий вариант тоже не покатил: `gcc source1.c source2.c -L. -L/lib64  mylib.a -lm -static`

Comment: Вот этого не знаю :-( Но попробуйте убрать `-L.`.

Comment: Если убрать -L то тогда будут ошибки связанные с тем что не найдены библиотеки *.a, а в остальном все тоже самое будет)

Comment: Ну а `libm` при этом всё-таки находит?

Comment: Нет, в том и проблема:-( Завтра попробую с `-v` и `--verbose` собрать может что-то проясниться)

Comment: [вот здесь][1] советуют установить пакет `glibc-static`


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284009/cannot-find-lc-and-lm-in-g-linux

Comment: @alexander barakin - спасибо, похоже это то что надо

Comment: Попробовал смоделировать у себя `Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`  
 (сразу скажу, libm.a установлена в /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu). Свою библиотеку назвал libtz.a и она лежит вместе с компилируемым файлом. Как и ожидалось -- `gcc c.c -lm -L. -ltz --static` прекрасно отрабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вероятно, линковщик не может найти статическую сборку библиотеки `libm` — файл `libm.a`.

этот файл входит либо в пакет `glibc-static`, либо `glibc-devel`.

установить его в `centos` можно командой `yum install glibc-static` (`yum install glibc-devel`).